# How to initialize List<T> in Kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin

I see Kotlin has a [`List<out E>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html) collection and I was wondering about different ways to initialize one. In Java, I could write:

```
List<String> geeks = Arrays.asList("Fowler", "Beck", "Evans");
```

How can I achieve the same in Kotlin?

Comment: With [`listOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html) ?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

[`listOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html) top-level function to the rescue:

```
val geeks = listOf("Fowler", "Beck", "Evans")
```

Comment: Calling [listOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html) without any parameter gets you an empty list, or just call [emptyList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/empty-list.html) to make it more readable.

Comment: There's also [arrayListOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/array-list-of.html)

Comment: Is it mutable for later modification?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky The returned type is a read-only `List<T>`, so one shouldn't assume that it is mutable.

Answer (score 32):

Both the upvoted answers by [Ilya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36897638/1421925) and [gmariotti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36946623/1421925) are good and correct. Some alternatives are however spread out in comments, and some are not mentioned at all.

This answer includes a summary of the already given ones, along with clarifications and a couple of other alternatives.

### Immutable lists ([`List`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html))

Immutable, or read-only lists, are lists which cannot have elements added or removed.

- As Ilya points out, [`listOf()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html) often does what you want. This creates an immutable list, similar to [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) in Java.
- As [frogcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/709528/frogcoder) states in a comment, [`emptyList()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/empty-list.html) does the same, but naturally returns an empty list.
- [`listOfNotNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of-not-null.html) returns an immutable list excluding all `null` elements.

### Mutable lists ([`MutableList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html))

Mutable lists can have elements added or removed.

- gmariotti suggests using [`mutableListOf()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-list-of.html), which typically is what you want when you need to add or remove elements from the list.
- [Greg T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3272593/greg-t) gives the alternative, [`arrayListOf()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/array-list-of.html). This creates a mutable [`ArrayList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/index.html). In case you really want an `ArrayList` implementation, use this over `mutableListOf()`.
- For other [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) implementations, which have not got any convenience functions, they can be initialized as, for example, `val list = LinkedList<String>()`. That is simply create the object by calling its constructor. Use this only if you really want, for example, a [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html) implementation.

Comment: Just an addition: I need often a mutable list with a generic type parameter. `val mutableList = mutableListOf<T>()`with `<String>` or another class as type parameter.

Answer (score 17):

Just for adding more info, Kotlin offers both immutable `List` and `MutableList` that can be initialized with `listOf` and `mutableListOf`. If you're more interested in what Kotlin offers regarding Collections, you can go to the official reference docs at [Collections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html).

Answer (score 10):

Let me explain some use-cases :
let's create an immutable(non changeable) list with initializing items :

```
val myList = listOf("one" , "two" , "three")
```

let's create a Mutable (changeable) list with initializing fields :

```
val myList = mutableListOf("one" , "two" , "three")
```

Let's declare an immutable(non changeable) and then instantiate it :

```
lateinit var myList : List<String>
// and then in the code :
myList = listOf("one" , "two" , "three")
```

And finally add some extra items to each :

```
val myList = listOf("one" , "two" , "three")
myList.add() //Unresolved reference : add, no add method here as it is non mutable 

val myMutableList = mutableListOf("one" , "two" , "three")
myMutableList.add("four") // it's ok
```

Answer (score 6):

In this way, you can initialize the List in Kotlin

```
val alphabates : List<String> = listOf("a", "b", "c")
```

Answer (score 2):

There is one more way to build a list in Kotlin that is as of this writing in the experimental state but hopefully should change soon.

```
inline fun <E> buildList(builderAction: MutableList<E>.() -> Unit): List<E>
```

> Builds a new read-only List by populating a MutableList using the given builderAction and returning a read-only list with the same elements.

**Example:**

```
val list = buildList {
    testDataGenerator.fromJson("/src/test/resources/data.json").forEach {
        add(dao.insert(it))
    }
}
```

For further reading check the official [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/build-list.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize without type:

```
var temp: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
```