# How to initialize an empty ArrayList in Kotlin?

Tags: arraylist, kotlin, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an empty arraylist:

```
var mylist: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
```

When I want to set value in it I got this error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

The question is: How can I initialize my list?

Comment: Don't use `set` but `add.`. Also use the factory instead of constructor: `val list = mutableListOf<Int>()`. Also note I specified `val` instead of `var` (it has nothing to do with the list's mutability).

Answer (score 129, accepted):

According to the [api-doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/array-list-of.html):

```
val list = arrayListOf<Int>()
```

This is also mentioned here: [How to initialize List in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896801/how-to-initialize-listt-in-kotlin#36897638)
.

Comment: Isn't an arrayList different from an array in kotlin?

Comment: @SMBiggs See SO [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76051010/what-is-the-difference-between-array-list-and-arraylist-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 45):

I suggest you write

```
var myList: ArrayList<Int> = arrayListOf()
```

Comment: `val myList = arrayListOf<Int>()` reads much better.

Comment: What if it's an array, not an arrayList?

Comment: you can do this with ```val value= Array(20) { 0 }```